# XCode 4: Archive is using old project name

Tags: xcode, rename, archive, organizer

I have renamed my project successfully.

However, when I create an archive (I'm ready to upload it to the store), Organizer is showing the archive named with the OLD project name.

In fact I have renamed this project twice!   And it is showing the original name.

I don't know if this is going to trip me up, but it is annoying.   Where is this name determined?

In my info.plist everything is using the default values,  and in my target's build settings Product Name is correctly set.

I can't see anywhere else this old name might be lurking. Cleaning the project and restarting Xcode doesn't do a thing.

How can I correct this?

PS XCode 4.0.2

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme in the list on the left select Archive and you will get a form with text box Archive Name where you can make your change.

This works for Xcode 4.6 + for sure.

Answer (score 22):

**EDIT: Out of date!**

It seems that the scheme doesn't get renamed when the project gets renamed.

I guess this is one of the low priority things on the Xcode team's  to do list...

Anyway, just needed to rename the scheme

Comment: This answer is out of date. See Sihad's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is fine, it's just not obvious on Xcode,

1) To edit your scheme, use Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes, once there, you will see the list, I know; there is no "edit" for the name as such, however, click on your scheme name twice (slow click), the name will allow you to edit it and change it.

2) To edit your Archive name (i.e. the name that appear under the scheme when you archive on Organiser), use Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Goto Archive (left menu) -> and then enter what you like in the Archive Name.

I hope that help, the above answers are correct, just wanted to share the exact steps on how to edit, as I had one of those moments myself for not seeing an EDIT button there...

Regards

Heider

Comment: thanks helped me changing the old project name.